# Bitmap loading from url using Async tasks and handling concurrency

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask

I used the same code as shown in the link[Multithreading For performance](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html), but I cant see the image on the screen.

Comment: Can you post your code, its difficult to say whats happening without seeing exactly what you are doing, not just referring to their code? Did you look at Logcat to see if there are any exceptions being thrown?

Comment: no need to use async task , threads use simple methods as given you in example.

Comment: Please post your code, we would need that to help you out

Answer (score 0):

Dear Its 2012 try using latest functions for downloading image or something else

it has following:
1) progress bar
2) provide url in download manager class
3) register BroadcastReceiver to get downloaded data after it is downloaded.

[Download Manager Class Example](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/)

Hope this is easiest one.

Answer (score 0):

Believe me, you don't want to do it yourself manually if it's for UI purposes. Way too messy on Android, if you just want to display the picture to the user. Just use http://loopj.com/android-smart-image-view/ for those scenarios, it also includes caching and will help you with out-of-memory issues that Android is prone to.

When you get it working,  make sure to read how SmartImageViews work internally, you can probably learn a few things.